# Passing Values to print only, pdf preview, or open in excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion

I have two reports: Checklist and Location. Depending on which report is chosen decides the action of the form of what path to take. I also have a select that ask the user whether or not they want to print automatically, preview as a pdf, or open in excel.

```
<select name="Format" required>
    <option selected value="">Select Format</option>
    <option value="print">Print</option>
    <option value="pdf">Preview</option>
    <option value="xls">Excel</option>
</select>
```

I am curious of how I am suppose to forward this information in order to do the queries and process the choice the user is requesting. I am sure people do things like this all the time. Would anyone like to share any examples or advice - stepping stones to get me on the right path? Thanks in advance!

Tagged below are all the languages I am using that I could use to achieve this goal.

Comment: Advice.  Recognize that display options have nothing to do with getting the data to display.  Your queries will be the same no matter what the final display is.

Comment: So how would you do it in CF Dan? Right now I have the form action go to the queries.cfm. Two different cfms. How would you tie it together? Pass the value through the url to the new cfm and then some how have it route from the query page?

Comment: Do the same thing in both pages.  Run the query and do anything else you have to do that is irrespective of the display.  Then do some conditional logic on the display choice and write the appropriate code for each choice.  If there is anything identical in both pages, put the common code in an included file.

Comment: You have many options on how to forward the data, but we don't know if you mean you are trying to "forward the data" to a different page, or to the server, or both? Are you using AJAX, CF, both? If you are forwarding to different pages, then just query parameters in the url to send over whatever information you want the next page to have, like `foo?print=1` and then just look for the presence or absence of these parameters on the next page, and then when its time to send things to the server, you can POST all your options to the server endpoint for typical processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to send data to a different page, then you can use query parameters for that. One option is to build the query parameters as users update the dropdown:

```js
var select = $('select[name=Format]');

function buildUrl(option) {
  return 'some/endpoint?option=' + option;
}

select.change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var url = buildUrl(value);
  console.log('URL to call:', url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Format" required>
  <option selected value="">Select Format</option>
  <option value="print">Print</option>
  <option value="pdf">Preview</option>
  <option value="xls">Excel</option>
</select>
```

and then you can use JavaScript or CF to detect the presence (or absence) of the query parameters to meet your app's requirements.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using pdfmake on my reports. It has the option to generate a report with Excel, Print, or download pdf. All you have to do is pass a json array. You can read the documentation on github. Here's the link: [PDFMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake)

This might not be the best answer but it would be a stepping stone for you.